# Why concatMap is not working as expected?

Tags: rxjs, concatmap

please see my code below

```
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take, mergeMap, concatMap, switchMap, exhaustMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const frameworks = ['Backbone', 'Angular', 'React', 'Vue'];

const getRecruits = agency => new Observable(observer => {
  console.log('agency', agency);
  interval(1000).pipe(
    take(5)
  ).subscribe(val => observer.next(`${agency} Developer ${val}`));
});

// concatMap
interval(3000).pipe(
  take(4),
  map(val => frameworks[val]),
  concatMap(agency => getRecruits(agency))
).subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

and this is my output:

[image]

I expected after Backbone finished, it would have continued with Angular, React and then Vue. But the execution stopped after Backbone

any explanations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**key knowledge**

[conactMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap) only emits the next observable as far as the previous is completed.

**reason**

If you keep this in mind and have a look onto *getRecruits* you can see that the inner interval observable closes, but actually your newly create one `new Observable(observer => ...)` does not, because you only emit values to the `observer` via `next`. You can complete the returned observable the same time your your inner subscription fires complete.

**solution**

```
const getRecruits = agency => new Observable(observer => {
  interval(1000).pipe(
    take(5)
  ).subscribe(
    val => observer.next(`${agency} Developer ${val}`),
    () => void 0, // You can use void 0 for no emit
    () => observer.complete() // Your interval source completes here and you call the new Observalbe to be completed
  );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To finish it you need to call `observer.complete`, currently the code calls `observer.next` only.

to do it please change your code like that

```
).subscribe(
  val => observer.next(`${agency} Developer ${val}`),
  () => observer.complete(),
  () => observer.complete(),
);
```

Comment: I just saw you answered the same way I did some minutes ago. Sorry for repetitive answering, but I didn't update the question since some minutes and I added some notes to my answer. I highly appreciate and recommend your short answer style!